# Bluetooth®LE Add-onボード SPRESENSE-BLE-EVK-701を用いたBluetooth接続について

Tags: spresense, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

BLEボードと、スマホアプリのBLEToolを使ってSPRESENSEとスマホをBluetooth接続したいのですが、”Connected succesfully”というメッセージが出ません。（要は接続ができない。”waiting for connection”のメッセージまでは出るのですが…）
問題なのが、メインボード単体にBLEボードを繋げた状態でトライするとBluetooth接続ができるのですが、メインボードに拡張ボードを繋げ、メインボードとBLEボードを繋げた状態でトライすると、Bluetooth接続ができなくなります。
メインボード単体では接続できるのでBLEボードのピンをメインボードに差し込む位置や、プログラミングの方に問題があるとは考えてはいないのですが、何か原因が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

拡張ボードを差した状態でメインボード側のUART2端子(BLEボード)を使用する場合は、
拡張ボードにあるジャンパJP10(UART SWと書かれているやつ)をショートする必要があります。

ドキュメントだと、ここら辺に書かれています。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_拡張ボード](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_uartの使用方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_uart%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

自分も同じ悩みに遭遇したことがあり、ジャンパを接続すればあっさり動きました。